# If product exist in category, then display HTML

Tags: magento2, php, html

I am trying to display a badge on the product card (category page) and single product page, if the product exist in a certain category. So if the product exist in the category "Chairs" or category ID 13, then the badge would be displayed.

I am editing the list.phtml template and have tried a lot of different options, but none of them work.

This is my current code:

```
<?php $yourCatIds = array(13);
$productCats = $_product->getAvailableInCategories();

if (count(array_intersect($yourCatIds,$productCats))) {
    echo '<div class="badge">BADGE</div>';
}
?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> You can get product's categories ID and check if your id (Chair's ID -
> 13) in array then add condition as below.

```
<?php $yourCatIds = 13;
      $productCats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
      if (in_array($yourCatIds,$productCats)) {
        echo '<div class="badge">BADGE</div>';
      }
?>
```

Comment: I have tried, but this doesn't seem to return anything. It won't even return the category ID's.

Comment: make sure your product is loaded and your are not using any block method in that case it can may not load all attributes.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have tried, but I still can't get it to work :(

Comment: if there is a block you might want to add cacheable  = "false" to the xml of the block / template. Sometimes flat and cache is annoying. Also make sure your product is loaded with the correct store.

Answer (score 0):

**You can achieve this in the following way**

```
<?php 
     $yourCatIds = array(13);
     $productCats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
     if(count(array_intersect($yourCatIds,$productCats))) {
         echo '<div class="badge">BADGE</div>';
     }
?>
```

Comment: Please upvote these answer if useful.